# Fix a UIView at the bottom of the screen without Auto-layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autoresizingmask

In my app, there is a UITabController that has 3 tabs. They all have a search button that should stay at the bottom of the screen. The 3rd Tab has a UIScrollView and the button must ignore the scroll(the button must be anchored to the bottom of the screen and should be unaffected by scroll). I cannot use auto layout in the app(MUST do this with auto resizing). I have tried all possible combinations with struts and springs and yet the search button stays somewhere in the middle of these screen(Only an issue with the tab that has UIScrollView). Am I missing something? Do methods differ, when handling UIScroll View?

Comment: check my answer i have edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height
```

By using this `SCREEN_WIDTH` and `SCREEN_HEIGHT` you can set your view to bottom of your screen.

You can set button frame as

```
x = 0
Y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 46
Width = SCREEN_WIDTH
Height = 46
```

So that button will stay at bottom.

Hope it helps.

Comment: how do i programatically anchor the uiview(my button) to that point?

Comment: what is size of your button.

Comment: (320,46)..the scroll view has a mechanism to increase the height(of the whole view and add subviews and remove them)..so no matter what the screen size is, the Search Button must be tied to the bottom

Comment: the width of the button is equal to the width of the screen

Comment: This worked beautifully. I am relatively new to ios dev, so I hav no idea how autoresizing(and auto layout) would work. Can you point me to a tutorial for autoresizing masks?

Comment: You can check this link   www.raywenderlich.com where you can find good demo for ios.